# When using the function PUBLISH in matlab, how do I print the answer of each of command under the specific command?

Tags: matlab

For example, let's say I have the following commands

```
a= [ 1 2 4 ];
length(a)
sum(a)
```

When I use `publish` I want to have the following:

```
length(a)

ans = 
3

sum(a)

ans = 
7
```

Right now, I have the commands first and then the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `publish`, the answers shown for each code section.

To insert a new code section, use `%%` like that:

```
a = [1 2 4];
length(a)
%%
sum(a)
```

So in file the answers will separated:

[image]